# Getting Data from 2 edit fields in sublayout in Android

Tags: android

I want to get data from two edit fields in a sub layout . See the image below.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR7sn.jpg)

I am writing code to dynamically add sub layouts with 2 edit fields in it. I can get the text from both edit fields manually with this code.

```
 View childView = subLayout.getChildAt(0);//0 for 1st field, 1 for 2nd field.
 String s = ((TextView)childView).getText().toString();
```

but how to get data from both using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, every child in your layout is subclass of the `View` class. Once you get a child, use `instanceof` to check if this child is actually a `TextView`

```
for(int i=0;i<subLayout.getChildCount();i++){
       View v=subLayout.getChildAt(i);
       if(v instanceof TextView){
       Stirng s = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
       }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You must to create database  somthih like this[enter link description here](https://www.video2brain.com/en/lessons/sqlite-databases-in-android)

Comment: really? Or just some spam?